# How do you make and use a POST URL?

Tags: url, post, http-post, slack-api

I'm currently messing with Slack integrations (https://slack.com/integrations), and trying to make one myself.  I know that when my command is hit, it will POST something like this to a URL:

```
 token=whatever
 team_id=12345
 channel_id=ABC123
 channel_name=test
 timestamp=1355517523.000005
 user_id=USER123
 user_name=Steve
 text=googlebot: What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?
 trigger_word=googlebot:
```

I understand how this works conceptually, but I've never actually used POST before.

Let's just say I want to take this data and put it in a Google Spreadsheet or on a web page.  What does the POST URL have to actually consist of?  Can I just link a static URL to a file I have on GitHub?  Do I have to write in something like PHP, or would JavaScript do?  How do I actually take in this input?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To make a post, you either need a browser extension, like Postman:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Or you could use an HTML form submission

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

or a Javascript AJAX request

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

finally, you can do it on the command line, using:

```
curl -X POST http://example.com/test -d'postdatahere'
```

Comment: But what is the POST URL? What is in that file? Because I'm POSTing to it, does that mean in the URL I have to GET something?

Comment: Ahh, /test can be whatever you want. It could be a Java application, a Python web app, a Perl/PHP script. All these languages have libraries for receiving/processing POST requests. Then, you'd have to write the code to translate the contents of the POST into whatever you want (HTML if you just want to display a web page, Google API calls if you want to create a spreadsheet).

Comment: You need some sort of server to run it on as well. I don't think that you could host this sort of thing on GitHub.